# Opening file geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

How do I open a file geodatabase using QGIS 3.6.2?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: click the add vector button (red circle)

[image]

---

Step 2: select directory, openFileGDB, and file path (red arrow)

[image]

---

Step 3: select all layers (red circle)
[image]

---

Done!
You just added all layers to QGIS

Comment: When answering your own question, it's more important that the answer match the question.  Here the question specifies "using QGIS 3.6.2" and your answer shows "QGIS 2.18.16".